# Is there a reliable way how to run virtualized Docker / Kubernetes stack on Windows?

Tags: windows, vagrant, kubernetes

Are there any up-to-date guides, or VM images of some Linux VM + Kubernetes that I could run on Windows? Both VMWare, VirtualBox or Vagrant images would help. I'm trying to set up a development environment. (There is no production environment yet, but it will be most likely self-hosted.)

I tried installing several Vagrant templates for Kubernetes linked from their github documentation, but they were specifically marked as not supported on Windows; I tried compiling Kubernetes 0.15 from source under CoreOS and Boot2Docker, but ran into problems with either.

Since my ops skill set is relatively low, I'd sleep easier if I could use a template that was set up by someone who knew what they're doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you install Docker on Windows (see the [Docker instructions](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/)), you can then follow the guide to run [Kubernetes locally via Docker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker.md) and then once you are comfortable with that try running [Multi-Node Kubernetes Using Docker](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/docs/getting-started-guides/docker-multinode.md).

Comment: Thanks, I've tried that several times, but it didn't work for me. For some reason, one v0.15 kubelet spawns three v0.14.1 containers, which does not seem right. When I run kubectl get nodes, I only get `127.0.0.1   Schedulable   <none>    NotReady` and from logs it only seems that _something_ cannot connect to _some_ API.

Comment: It looks like when the guide was updated to v0.15.0 it wasn't done correctly. Both https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master-multi.json and https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/images/hyperkube/master.json still reference v0.14.1 instead of v0.15.0. I'll file a bug and let you know when this is fixed.

Comment: Here's the bug link: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/kubernetes/issues/7292